# kubernetes from a running pod, get only required elements via -o yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

Generally in the kubernetes we can create definition files. for non-running and running pods, namespaces, deployments etc. If we generate yaml file for non running and non existing pods it create required defination file. However, if we have to get the defination file from running pod it also generates lots tags of live environment.

How to get only required elements while we generate yaml defination from a running pod

Is there any way if we can avoid getting below details after we generate pod yaml file from a running pod

For example if we see that after running below command it also generates lot of not required elements.

```
k get po nginxs14 -n=devs14 -o yaml>pod1.yaml

like:

metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Pod","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"run":"nginx"},"name":"nginxs14","namespace":"devs14"},"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-24T11:09:56Z"
  labels:
    run: nginx
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:run: {}
      f:spec:
        f:containers:
          k:{"name":"nginx"}:
            .: {}
            f:image: {}
            f:imagePullPolicy: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:ports:
              .: {}
              k:{"containerPort":9080,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                .: {}
                f:containerPort: {}
                f:protocol: {}
            f:readinessProbe:
              .: {}
              f:failureThreshold: {}
              f:httpGet:
                .: {}
                f:path: {}
                f:port: {}
                f:scheme: {}
              f:periodSeconds: {}
              f:successThreshold: {}
              f:timeoutSeconds: {}
            f:resources: {}
            f:terminationMessagePath: {}
f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
        f:dnsPolicy: {}
        f:enableServiceLinks: {}
        f:restartPolicy: {}
        f:schedulerName: {}
        f:securityContext: {}
        f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-04-24T11:09:56Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
          k:{"type":"ContainersReady"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Initialized"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Ready"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:containerStatuses: {}
        f:hostIP: {}
        f:phase: {}
        f:podIP: {}
        f:podIPs:
          .: {}
```

Comment: A good practice is to keep the original YAML files in source control, either checked in with the application they deploy or in a separate repository of deploy-time configuration.  Then you don't need to retrieve and modify the configuration out of the cluster; change the YAML files, get code reviews, check them in, and use only `kubectl apply -f` (or similar tools like Helm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> after running below command it also generates lot of not required elements

A large part of the problem you describe is the `managedFields:`. I agree this is very verbose and mostly annoying output.

However, this is now fixed. If you upgrade to `kubectl` version 1.21+ this is [not shown as default](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90066#issuecomment-814063884). Now you need to add `--show-managed-fields` to show these fields.